# Dynamically Change Range in Excel Chart Without VBA?

Tags: excel, charts

I'm charting values and I need to change the start and stop of the range dynamically. The chart is plotting from a sheet that has data for 5 forecast days. Each line in the chart represents a forecast day. Every day new data is added to the sheet, so there are more entries for each forecast day. Here is an example:

**=SERIES("Day 4",sheet!$B$2:$B$49,sheet!$F$147:$F$193,5)**

I need Excel to find the start and stop row numbers for each forecast day and change them every time there is new data. So the range for forecast day 4 $F$147:$F$193 will change to $F$148:$F$194, etc.

Is it possible to do this in a formula? I really don't want to mess with VBA if I can avoid it.

Comment: A dynamic named range could have its terminating cell easily defined with a formula. Not sure how you would want to approach the first cell of the range.

Comment: I should specify that forecast day is in column C. I'm charting values from  columns D through F and I need their ranges to change based on the first and last row numbers of column C. I'm using =(MATCH("2",C:C,0)) to get the first number (named Day_4_start) and =(MATCH("2",C:C,0)+(COUNTIF(C:C,"2"))-1) to get the second number (named Day_4_end). I need to figure out how to change  $F$147:$F$193  to $F$Day_4_start:$F$Day_4_end or something to that effect

Comment: tbh, I really do not understand how you are getting the first relevant day with `=(MATCH("2",C:C,0))`.

Comment: I'm looking for the first and last instances of "2" which represents a forecast day. So today there are 55 or so forecast day 2's starting at August 1st. Tomorrow there will be 56 forecast day 2's etc. I need the row numbers of the first and last instance of each group of 5 forecast days to change the range for the values I'm looking for from each of those days.

Comment: There are thousands of examples of Dynamic Range formula on the internet (and on SO)

Comment: Thanks, I've tried a lot of them. I'm not sure what I want to do is possible without VBA. I tried turning the MATCH into a named range, but Excel wouldn't accept it in the formula bar.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a defined starting date, like "01/01/2017" for example, you could use "TODAY()" to count the number of days and increment based on that number.

For example:

```
=DAYS(TODAY(),DATE(2017,1,1))
```

returns 263 today, and 264 tomorrow. You could add/subtract this number to change the values of your series ranges each day; e.g. `($F$ &  =DAYS(TODAY(),DATE(2017,1,1)) - 116 & ":$F$ & =DAYS(TODAY(),DATE(2017,1,1)) - 70)` would give you the desired outcome.

Edit:
Because you apparently can't define chart series using formulas, create an intermediate data range outside of your list/table of data (you could even use named ranges without a cell reference - doesn't matter). This range should be the same size as the data range you would like to display on the chart. Then make your dynamic range references to your data to all the cells within this range; e.g. `=F &  =DAYS(TODAY(),DATE(2017,1,1)) - 116` or whatever the formula needs to be, but do this for all the cells referenced. Then make your chart series reference to *those* cells that contain the dynamic formulas.

Comment: I can't put formulas in the chart series range

Comment: @BillHambone then use an intermediate cell range that changes instead, and leave the cell reference in the chart series static.

Comment: Can you share an example?

Comment: Use the cells the chart is referring to, e.g. `sheet!$B$2:$B$49` & `sheet!$F$147:$F$193` as  a redirect. So you update the information within cells B2:B49 and F147:F193 depending on which data you want to appear today. I'll try to post an edit here with some screenshots when I get a second if that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Not at a computer still, so no screenshot, but I tried to explain what I meant in my answer. Did that help?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clearer. This isn't based on date, just numbers,1,2,3,4,5 in column C. Those represent forecast days from today. I need to find the row numbers of the first and last "4" for instance, and use those numbers to change the range for the chart. So if the first "4" is at row 148 and the last is at 194, the range for my chosen value will change from $F$147:$F$193, to $F$148:$F$194. I need to use the number of specific numbers in column C to change the range for the values from column F. Is that possible?